# Loading Core Data relationships from existing database ID relationships

Tags: core-data, restkit

I have an application that has lots of data in tables, and I'm writing a mobile app that gets a small portion of the data. The data in tables uses IDs for relations, and I'm trying to load it into a Core Data model and preserve the relationships.

But it doesn't seem like there's an easy way to tell Core Data, "For this relationship, I want a foreign key to this other table." Instead, I have this monstrosity (this is a simplified version of only one of six asynchronous RestKit queries that are coming back to fill the database):

```c
[manager postObject:nil path:@"api/shiftservice/get" parameters:@{@"workerIds": @[@1]} success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"Loaded shifts: %d", [[mappingResult array] count]);
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [AppDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSSet *positions = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"NWPosition"];
    NSDictionary *positionDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (NWPosition *position in positions) [positionDict setValue:position forKey:position.positionId.stringValue];

    NSSet *workers = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"NWWorker"];
    NSDictionary *workerDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (NWWorker *worker in workers) [workerDict setValue:worker forKey:worker.workerId.stringValue];

    NSSet *shifts = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"NWShift"];
    for (NWShift *shift in shifts)
    {
        NWPosition *position = [positionDict valueForKey:shift.positionId.stringValue];
        position.shifts = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"NWShift" withPredicateFormat:@"positionId = %d", position.positionId];
        shift.position = position;

        NSSet *tradesAsGetShift = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"NWTrade" withPredicateFormat:@"getShiftId = %@", shift.shiftId];
        for (NWTrade *trade in tradesAsGetShift) trade.getShift = shift;
        shift.tradesAsGetShift = tradesAsGetShift;

        NSSet *tradesAsGiveShift = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"NWTrade" withPredicateFormat:@"giveShiftId = %@", shift.shiftId];
        for (NWTrade *trade in tradesAsGiveShift) trade.giveShift = shift;
        shift.tradesAsGiveShift = tradesAsGiveShift;

        NWWorker *worker = [workerDict valueForKey:shift.workerId.stringValue];
        worker.shifts = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"NWShift" withPredicateFormat:@"workerId = %d", worker.workerId];
        shift.worker = worker;
    }
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to load shifts with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

I'm using a modified version of Matt Gallagher's One-Line Fetch at http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/core-data-one-line-fetch.html for the `fetchObjectsForEntityName`.

Anyway, this seems pretty horrible to me, like I'm missing something obvious. Is there some way to just tell Core Data about database-style foreign keys? Is there an easy way to populate them, if there isn't? Because doing this many fetches for every single entity sure doesn't seem like the right way to do it. And if RestKit helps out here, so much the better.

Comment: RestKit should be dealing with the foreign keys (Core Data does not). Show the JSON you receive and the mappings you have. Have you added foreign key relationships into the mappings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Wain and his insightful comment, I managed to get RestKit to do this for me in a reasonably-elegant fashion. Here is how I set up the foreign key relationships. I set up both ends of each relationship so that either set of data could come in first and the relationship would still get populated properly.

First, I set up the manager, telling it to use JSON serialization:

```c
RKManagedObjectStore *store = [AppDelegate managedObjectStore];

RKObjectManager *manager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:oauthClient];
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:manager];
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[manager.HTTPClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[manager registerRequestOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[manager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[manager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
manager.managedObjectStore = store;
```

Next, I set up connections and response descriptors:

```c
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [AppDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSDictionary *orgRels = [[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NWOrg" inManagedObjectContext:context] relationshipsByName];
NSDictionary *positionRels = [[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NWPosition" inManagedObjectContext:context] relationshipsByName];
// ...

NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

NSArray *orgConnections =
@[[self connectionForRelation:@"positions" localKey:@"orgId" foreignKey:@"orgId" withRels:orgRels],
  [self connectionForRelation:@"workers" localKey:@"orgId" foreignKey:@"orgId" withRels:orgRels]];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:
    [self entityMappingForName:@"NWOrg" fromDictionary:@{@"orgId": @"orgId", @"orgName": @"orgName"} withKey:@"orgId" andConnections:orgConnections]
    method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"api/orgservice/get" keyPath:nil statusCodes:statusCodes]];

NSArray *positionConnections =
@[[self connectionForRelation:@"org" localKey:@"orgId" foreignKey:@"orgId" withRels:positionRels],
  [self connectionForRelation:@"shifts" localKey:@"positionId" foreignKey:@"positionId" withRels:positionRels]];
[manager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:
    [self entityMappingForName:@"NWPosition" fromDictionary:@{@"positionId": @"positionId", @"orgId": @"orgId", @"name": @"positionName"} withKey:@"positionId" andConnections:positionConnections]
    method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"api/positionservice/get" keyPath:nil statusCodes:statusCodes]];

// ...
```

Then, I was able to do the simple request, and it worked great:

```c
[manager postObject:nil path:@"api/shiftservice/get" parameters:@{@"workerIds": @[@1]}
    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"Loaded shifts: %d", [[mappingResult array] count]);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to load shifts with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

Note: This used a few helper methods, which I will reproduce here:

```c
- (RKConnectionDescription *)connectionForRelation:(NSString *)relation
    localKey:(NSString *)localKey foreignKey:(NSString *)foreignKey 
    withRels:(NSDictionary *)rels
{
    return [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:rels[relation]
        attributes:@{localKey: foreignKey}];
}

- (RKEntityMapping *)entityMappingForName:(NSString *)name
    fromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict withKey:(NSString *)key
{
    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:name
        inManagedObjectStore:[AppDelegate managedObjectStore]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:dict];
    mapping.assignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;
    mapping.assignsNilForMissingRelationships = YES;
    mapping.identificationAttributes = @[key];

    return mapping;
}

- (RKEntityMapping *)entityMappingForName:(NSString *)name
    fromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict withKey:(NSString *)key
    andConnections:(NSArray *)connections
{
    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [self entityMappingForName:name
        fromDictionary:dict withKey:key];
    for (RKConnectionDescription *connection in connections)
    {
        [mapping addConnection:connection];
    }
    return mapping;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but there should be no need to set the inverse relationships.